# vesafb / Ubuntu stucks in 5 dots when starts and ctrl alt f1 says something about vesafb mising lib

Tags: boot

please someone help me because i cant access my files anymore.
Ubuntu  stucks in 5 dots when starts and ctrl alt f1 says something about vesafb mising lib

Comment: Do you think you could have messed up your system by installing/uninstalling video drivers or modifying the configuration by hand? When did this start to happen?

Comment: it happened last may but i hadn't any time to check my pc again i was not home so now that i have time i try to fix it. I don't remember that i did anything like this i think i tryied to install the new beta version oneric it might be i don;t remember very whel and some problem happened there and caused this! @jorge-suarez-de-lis

Comment: We can't help you with that little information. At least make the effort to reproduce the message, and state your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i didn't managed to recover my system but i resqued my cryptographed files, using this tutorial

http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

also looking for similar problems in internet i found this page http://fraterneo.blogspot.gr/2012/02/error-al-arrancar-ubuntu-1110-con.html

i pasted it here if someone wants a full investigation about vesafb solutions in web.
Thanks ubuntu!